# Who loads DbRefs on java/morphia with default mongo driver

Tags: java, performance, mongodb, morphia

I have following class:

```
@Indexes({@Index("threadOrder,linf"),
    @Index("messageId,linf"),
    @Index("from, date"),
    @Index("linf,date")})
@Entity(noClassnameStored = true)
public class MessageEntry {
    @Id
    public ObjectId id;

    @Reference
    public MailSourceFile mailSourceFile;
    @Reference
    public Email from;
    @Reference
    public Linf linf;

    // some other primitive fields here

}
```

where MailSourceFile has some other nested @Reference's, Email and Linf don't have. The problem is that sometimes quering takes a long time (> 100ms) even when collection is loaded into memory by touch command. I need this time to be reduced, I believe this is possible. All the indeces are in place. I have 17M MessageEntry documents. The slow query looks like this:

```
ds.createQuery(MessageEntry.class).field("linf").equal(linf)
.field("threadOrder").in(threadOrders).asList();
```

usually there are ~15 integers in threadOrders array. My guess is that slowdown is caused by nested DBRefs, that produce extra queries each time I do this request. Who is loading these objects: morphia, mongo or java driver? Can I somehow avoid these requests? May be something else can be done to improve perfomance of this request? Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morphia loads those references when it deserializes your documents back in to the java object.  By default, it does this eagerly.  You can tell morphia to do lazy fetching by setting `lazy=true` on your `@Reference` annotation and you'll get back a proxified version of your object that will lazily fetch those references on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, enable slow query logging `db.setProfilingLevel(1)` (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/) to see what the underlying query is and start tracking your problem down from there. But evanchooly's approach will definitely help.